# How to easily find whether the contibuted modules have been updated or not?

Tags: updating

I am trying to upgrade my project form D6 to D7. I have used several contributed modules in my porject.

I am aware that I should check availability of all the contributed modules in version 7 before starting upgrade process.

In this case I need to check every independent contributed modules seperately whether it is available or not..

My question is:

> Is there any other easy way to check availability of all the
>   contributed modules via programatically or any other modules to do
>   this...

BTW : **Not using drush...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a web-crawler script which loops through the list of modules and scans the HTML to determine if a 7.x release of the module exist.

But a faster solution would probably be to do the manual check by looking up the module at d.o.

If you don't know if the module has a d7 release or not, you probably want to do a more thorough checkup anyways.

- Is the module stable (is it an alpha, beta, rc or point release)
- is the module used by others
- is the module actively maintained

These questions are very important and would be hard to check for programmatically - so even though a manual look at modules can be a bit tedious it is probably the best solution.

Comment: Also even if there is a D7 version of a module, it may b a COMPLETE re-write, and require a rework of your original site feature.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to attempt an upgrade from D6 to D7, you really should consider using Drush.  Really strongly.  The [Drush Site Upgrade](http://drupal.org/project/drush_sup) command will save you a lot of time, and as a bonus, it will tell you the upgrade status of your D6 modules, and will recommend alternate modules for some modules with no upgrade path, but for which alternatives exist.

If you really don't want to use Drush, you can use the [Upgrade Status](http://drupal.org/project/upgrade_status) module.  It also has an upgrade assist block that will help you walk through the upgrade process manually.